# Python HTTP proxy Raw Sockets

Tags: python, sockets, http, proxy

I'm trying to implement a http proxy using raw sockets. Basically the idea is getting a request from the client , sending the request to the server , then getting the response , and sending back to the client. 
It looks easy but i have been trying to figuring out for about 2 days.
Here the response gets corrupted . Thanks :)

```
import socket
import sys
import requests

def merr(requesti):
    hosti = requesti.split("Host: ")
    hosti = hosti[1]
    hosti = hosti.split("User-Agent: ")
    hosti = hosti[0]
    hosti = hosti.strip()
    return hosti

def merr_buff(data):
    try:
        temp = requesti.split("Content-Length:")
        temp = temp[1]
        temp = temp.split("\n")
        temp = temp[0]
        temp = temp.replace(" ","")
        print temp
        return temp
    except:
        pass



def dergo(requesti, hosti):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((hosti, 80))
    s.send(str(requesti))
    print requesti
    fdx = s.recv(10000)
    return str(fdx)


def bind():
    HOST = ''   
    PORT = 8080 

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    print 'Socket created'

    try:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error , msg:
        print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
        sys.exit()

    print 'Socket bind complete'

    s.listen(200)   

    print 'Socket now listening'

    conn, addr = s.accept()


    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(32000)
        if(data != ''):

            if(data.find("HTTP/1.1") != -1):


                target = merr(data)
                print  target
                response = dergo(data,target)
                conn.send(response)
                print "U dergua"

                conn.close()
                conn, addr = s.accept()




    s.close()


bind()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how the response is corrupt, but here are some problems I noticed with your code.

When you are sending data, [`socket.send`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) may not send the whole string, it will return the number of bytes transmitted. Instead you could use [`socket.sendall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall) which will attempt to send the whole string.

Similarly when receiving data from a socket, `socket.recv` will receive *up to* the buffer size specified, however this may not be the full content of the connection. You should keep calling `socket.recv` until the return value evaluates as false, for example (taken from the docs):

```
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

Try making these changes in your software and report back.

Comment: Hey peter thanks for the answer. so i changed the function dergo() and it takes very very long to load lets say 2-3 mins a website.
here is the full code http://pastebin.com/6umcTWHC
and when i said the data was corrupt was the content on the clients side was missing.

Comment: @Rt33nAlb0zZTeam you probably want to send the data back to the client as it comes in from the server rather than waiting for the connection from the server to close before sending